# Is the /tag command on Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I watched a video on YouTube that said that the tag command had been added to Bedrock Edition. When I went to the wiki it did not say it had been added. So I want to know if it really has been added? Also if it has is it for iOS?

Comment: Who do you believe more? Some random YouTuber or a page on a wiki  made by thousands of competent editors which is closely monitored by multiple moderators and referenced to by Mojang themselves on official Mojang pages? Also, if you trust noone, you could just try it.

Comment: I really don’t know? Sometimes wikis can be out dated. YouTube is the fastest source of information.

Comment: Ok, fair point. But usually you can still find pretty good changelogs, for example by Slicedlime or on Reddit. Just googling stuff like that should give you answers usually.

Comment: If you want a good wiki, see https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/ it is up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the /tag command is not in Pocket Edition as of the time of this answer. Just tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

As of Beta 1.9.0.2 released on, which is probably the version the YouTuber was playing, the `/tag` command’s was added. Unless you are in the beta program (which you can join using the instructions on [this](https://minecraftbedrock.fandom.com/wiki/Beta) page), you wouldn’t have been able to use it until the official release of Minecraft Bedrock 1.10.0, which happened on March 19, 2019. Furthermore, Beta is only available for Android, Xbox One, and Windows 10.